# Available parameters in window.open URL argument

Tags: javascript, window.open

In window.open javascript command (which opens a new windows) what options are available for first argument i.e URL?

One which is very common is http format (e.g. http://www.google.com). Which are the others?

Can i open a .pdf file from a shared folder using window.open?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags like c#.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myWindow = window.open(url, windowName[, windowFeatures]);
```

You can read more about it here: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Answer (score 0):

According the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.open):

> This is the URL to be loaded in the newly opened window. strUrl can be an HTML document on the web, it can be an image file or any type of file which is supported by the browser.

I assume this will work in most/all browsers, but the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't get too specific, so you might have to experiment.

Comment: you are sayin that strURL can be any document "on the web" what if i need to open a document from shared folder or from anywhere in the local PC, just to test that file is being opened up correctly

Comment: "It can be any type of file which is supported by the browser." Supposedly, local files will work. But I honestly don't know.